# Shared array of threads

Tags: arrays, multithreading, rust

`slaves_th` is a shared array of threads, below I want to call `join` on each thread but compiler throws error `slaves_th.lock().unwrap()` is not an iterator.

```rust
let slaves_th: Arc<Mutex<Vec<JoinHandle<()>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));

for _ in 0..8 {
    slaves_th
        .lock()
        .unwrap()
        .push(thread::spawn(move || println!("Hi")));
}

for th in slaves_th.lock().unwrap() {
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `MutexGuard<'_, Vec<JoinHandle<()>>>` is not an iterator
    match th.join() {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(_) => {
            println!("err join");
            ()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, like the compiler tells you, that `MutexGuard` doesn't implement `IntoIterator` and it can't since [`IntoIterator::into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) takes `self` by value but a `MutexGuard` has only a reference to the contents of the `Mutex`.

But you can turn your collection into an `Iterator` which lets you iterate over them.
Because you have to get the elements by value ([`JoinHandle::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) requires an owned `self`) your best choice is to use [`Vec::drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain):

```rust
for th in slaves_th.lock().unwrap().drain(..) {
```

You can use `take()` as well<sup>1</sup> with the difference that it consumes the `Vec` formerly contained inside the `Mutex` and replaces it with a new one. It thus frees the memory where `drain` keeps it allocated:

```rust
for th in std::mem::take(&mut *slaves_th.lock().unwrap()) {
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> As [@user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342) pointed out.</sup>

Comment: `std::mem::take()` is another good option, which works for any value that implements `Default`.

Comment: @user4815162342 `JoinHandle` does not implement `Default`, and also `take()` will leave an empty item in the place which is probably not what the programmer wants.

Comment: But `Vec` does implement `Default` irrespective of the contents @ChayimFriedman. Here you can use `take` if you want to free the memory that was taken up and `drain(..)` if you want to reuse it.